# How do I throw a Curveball?

Tags: pokemon-go

I noticed an XP bonus (+10 base if it just hits, no extra bonus for good throws) for a "curve ball" upon catching a Pokémon.

I have no idea how I did this, and would like to know how to replicate this for the future.

How do I throw a curveball?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

On the Capture Screen (where you see the Pokémon and the Pokéball), you may throw a curveball by following the below steps:

1. Place your finger on the Pokémon
2. Move your finger around in a circle in either direction
3. When you start to see the ball "sparkle," release it.
   [image: A pokéball glowing to indicate a curveball]
4. Pray that the ball lands on your target.

The Pokéball will curve back in the same direction that it was spun, so spinning the ball counter-clockwise will result in the ball curving left. As a result, you want to aim right of the Pokémon.

This method requires some practice, but is rather easy after getting the hang of it.

If a curveball is successfully thrown, the catch bonus multiplier for the Pokémon increases by a [factor of x1.7](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/guct-curveballs), making it as effective as a straight Excellent throw.

Comment: Worth noting that a "nice hit" (+10xp) when done with a curve ball will be an "excellent hit" (+100xp) instead.

Comment: @LCIII I don't think that's accurate. "Nice hit", "Great hit" and "Excellent hit" occur when the ball strikes the target within the shrinking circle when it is a certain size. These can be achieved with or without curving the ball and will replace the curve ball bonus.

Comment: **Please note:** Step 4 is the most critical part.

Comment: Throw bonuses and curveball bonuses are independent: http://i.imgur.com/q1KJXP2.png

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to spin the ball before releasing it. It is possible to throw a curve ball by not throwing the ball completely straight but instead throw straight but a little to the side right before you release it. I've gotten extremely good at doing this on accident and have on occasion managed to waste 30 balls because I kept throwing curves... Not so fun when you have fifteen super balls and are trying to catch a Gengar (unfortunately it fled when I finally managed to hit it...) same with the only Wartortle I've met in the wild... 
Now I usually get surprised by the curves because I tend to get curves even when it looks like it hit with a normal throw

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers submitted are too complex. They are over-thinking. I throw curveballs every time and my hit rate has gotten quite high. To throw a curve ball, simply draw a spiral or number six on the screen. Draw from the inside of the spiral outward. You can draw your spiral clockwise or counter-clockwise; it works either way. Only one loop around the spiral is necessary. More loops make it harder to aim, and serve no practical advantage.

And of course, practice, practice, practice.