# What are the possible catch bonuses and how much experience do they reward?

Tags: pokemon-go

I found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272611/how-do-i-throw-a-curveball), earlier, and found out that I can throw a curveball at pokémon to earn an increased experience bonus.

I have since noticed two more bonuses: "Great" and "Nice". I had assumed the bonuses were for throwing a pokéball with the 'catch circle' closer to the center, which according to the FAQ, increases the chances of actually catching the pokémon.

However, I have since noticed that the 'catch circle' is actually bigger in cases where I have earned a "Great" bonus. Despite appearing to be a less powerful throw, I earn more experience than when I earn a "Nice" bonus. "Great" nets me 50 experience, while "Nice" only nets 10 experience.

**What are the possible catch bonuses, and how much experience do they reward?**

For bonus points, every so often I am awarded an additional 10 experience points that are not accounted for on the experience screen. The screen lists my bonuses, and tells me how much experience I have earned, but I am clearly rewarded additional experience when it is added to my player. *Assuming this is another catch bonus, what could this be?*

Comment: Is your question about any bonus experience awarded at the experience screen, or just the the ones related to the type of throw performed?

Comment: @Wipqozn, all experience bonuses earnable during the catch sequence. For example, I had a 'phantom bonus' showing up that I wouldnt mind knowing about ("For bonus points... )

Comment: Made the previous comme t cause I didnt want to iverwrite the curve question Kaz wrote

Answer (score 83):

In addition to the +100 XP for catching a Pokemon, there are three throw bonuses in the game:

- **Nice Throw** - 10 XP
  You must hit the Pokemon anywhere inside the shrinking circle to be eligible for this reward.
- **Great Throw** - 50 XP
  You must hit the Pokemon within the shrinking circle when the diameter of the circle is no more than 70% the diameter of the white outer ring.
- **Excellent Throw** - 100 XP
  You must hit the Pokemon within the shrinking circle when the diameter of the circle is no more than 30% of the diameter of the white outer ring.

Throw bonuses do not stack, and you are only given credit for the last one you are eligible for in this list (For example, a Great Throw will give you the Great Throw bonus, but not the Nice Throw bonus).

These throw bonuses will grant a [catch bonus](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/guct-berry-throw-bonus-multipliers) as determined by the size of the circle. The equation for this is `catchBonus = 2 - circleRadius`, where 0 is the circle at its smallest possible point, and 1 is the white maxiumum radius.

In addition, there are three (stacking) bonuses that may be granted:

- **Curve Ball** - 10 XP
  These require you to throw a curveball and hit the Pokemon anywhere. There is a [how-to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272611/how-do-i-throw-a-curveball) available on this site. [A curveball will increase your catch rate](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/guct-curveballs) by x1.7 for every successful throw.
- **Bonus** - 100 XP
  This bonus is conferred on every 100th catch of a specific type of Pokemon. This bonus may be repeated. [[Source, line 258]](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf#file-game_master_v0_1-protobuf-L258)
- **New Pokemon** - 500 XP
  This bonus is conferred upon the first catch of any Pokemon, and is only given once per species.
- **First Throw** - 50 XP
  This bonus is conferred upon catching a Pokemon with the first Pokeball thrown. Berries do not negate one's ability to get this bonus.

Additionally, throw bonuses will confer a boost to the base catch rate for that Pokemon for that throw and all future throws.

There are also now [catch streak bonuses](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/231973328-Daily-Bonuses) that are applied upon the first catch of every day in a row:

- **Days 1-6** - 500 XP
  Upon catching at least one Pokemon anywhere from one to six days in a row, the game will confer a 500 XP bonus in addition to 600 Stardust.
- **Day 7** - 2500 XP
  After 7 days of continuously catching at least one Pokemon per day, the game will reward 2500 XP and 3000 Stardust.

Note that the streak will automatically reset after the seventh day. In other words, the eighth day of the streak will only confer a 500 XP bonus. The streak counter is also (obviously) reset if a day is missed. This reward can only be gotten once per day, and seems to reset at midnight in a player's local time zone.

Comment: I don't think that's entirely accurate, as I've gotten both the excellent bonus and a curve ball bonus simultaneously

Comment: @CaptainSaucer Perhaps Excellent is a unique case? I've never gotten one so I'm not sure. If you have a screenshot, post it and I'll add to the answer.

Comment: I believe curve ball can stack with any of the other three, however, I have never encountered nice/great/excellent in the same throw... and it wouldn't make sense if they could.

Comment: Yeah. I've been testing this nonstop and I have not been able to replicate stacks with _anything_, including Excellent. I definitely am throwing curveballs, too. Until someone can prove me wrong authoritative evidence (a screenshot, for example), I am very hesitant to claim that they can stack.

Comment: Ive started to notice my bonuses seem to only pop up (and I get great a lot) when I aim to flick the ball the instant it appears on the screen. Im starting to think the nice, great and excellent might actually be rewards for hitting the circle *on the first attempt*, or  rather, without letting the circle reset.

Comment: @Timelord64 That is likely a side effect of timing. In the split second where you throw into the circle, it probably shrinks to Great size. But I can confirm getting bonuses after 30 or so seconds of watching the circle, as well as repeat throws.

Comment: If you currently have a Lucky Egg active, the XP for the catch will also double, and catching a new Pokemon gives another 500 on top of the 100 for any catch. This gives a maximum possible XP for a catch of 1620 with all bonuses stacked.

Comment: Do we know if the milestone bonus is the "first 100 caught" or " every 100 caught"?

Comment: @dragonfire Every 100th

Comment: Just to note: in the past I was never able to stack Curveball with one of the other catch bonuses, but as of about 2 patches ago they seem to stack for me.

Comment: this is outdated now

Comment: Another thing you could add to this answer would be first catch of the day.... and also first throw catch. Here is the Pokemon go website https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/231973328-Daily-Bonuses   Daily bonus: The bonuses are day 1-6 500 XP and day 7 is 2500XP. And first through catch is 50 XP.