# Anyone else not getting bonus XP for "Nice!", "Great!" or "Excellent!" throws?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I literally just moments ago caught a Caterpie with a "Great!" throw, but when the XP screen came up after the successful catch, the bonus XP was not included in the tally. I've noticed this numerous times today, to the point where I almost grabbed a screenshot, but passed it off as maybe I was mistaken and got the "Nice!" or "Great!" (I hardly ever get "Excellent!" - I think maybe once or twice) label on one that then escaped, and then caught it on a subsequent "normal" throw.

I also can't exactly be sure, but I think I have received the bonus in the tally screen on throws that did not display the label.

Has anyone else noticed/experienced this recently?

This was seen in Android 6.0 on a DROID Turbo 2, Pokemon GO v0.31.0.

Comment: See the bolded sentence [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272677/what-are-the-possible-catch-bonuses-and-how-much-experience-do-they-reward/272797#272797).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Niantic, they have alleged that this is a bug

See: https://twitter.com/PokemonGoApp/status/761301330967326720

Comment: That's bad. The tweet sounds like instead of an exp bonus, the pokemon is more likely to escape/run away on "Nice!" and "Great!" throws than on normal throws.

Comment: ". . . and omits the XP bonus" - They confirmed that it is not only more likely they will escape, but also that the bonus XP is not appearing. Not really related but I find it odd that it took them 6 days after the patch was released to realize this bug happened!

Comment: Thanks, now I feel better about those seemingly easy guys getting away!