# Does the throw bonus affect catch rate?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokemon Go when catching a Pokemon the throw can be rewarded with an experience bonus (if the catch is successful). The possible throw bonuses are nice (10 exp), great (50), excellent (100) and curveball (10).

I have a theory, simply based on personal experiences, that achieving a throw bonus could increase the catch rate of the attempted capture.

Is there any evidence to suggest that this may actually be the case?

Comment: [Same answer but different question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281186/what-are-all-the-factors-which-affect-catch-chance?rq=1), Not sure I would call them duplicates which is why I haven't voted to close.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Good find, I didn't find that when I was looking earlier. I would say the answer to this question is a small part of the answer to that one... Not sure if that makes it a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right.
On [this site](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/catch-mechanics) you can find exact values for everything related to catching Pokémon.
The Values of the catching rate bonus are

- Curve Ball: x1.2*
- Nice Throw: x1.1*
- Great Throw: x1.3*
- Excellent Throw: x1.5

*Tentative until further testing

You have to multiply the catch rate with the values above. The given link also provides a table of catch rates for every Pokémon and Level.

For updated statistics, please have a look on Vemonus' answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/288122/138694

Comment: Great link, lots of helpful info there.

Comment: Maybe you mean **catching bonus** instead of **experience bonus**?

Comment: @SysDragon, sorry. Wrote the wrong word. Corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: Tentative until further testing means you shouldn't be answering definitively...as in, there's a good chance that the catch rate bonus is unaffected by the type of throw.

Comment: Also, your link: https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/catch-mechanics. credits its numbers to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongodev/comments/4vlnwj/pokemon_go_catch_mechanicsformula_discussion) which has now since been edited to say that `We considered these values as factors at first, but as they are called threshold, they probably have another impact (maybe thresholds that applies to normalized_reticle_size, see here)`

Comment: You should update your answer per https://thesilphroad.com/science/pokemon-go-throw-bonuses. Even better, you can drop a link to @Vemonus answer down below.

Answer (score 5):

It has been [stated](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272677/what-are-the-possible-catch-bonuses-and-how-much-experience-do-they-reward) that the catch rate does increase when you get a nice, great or excellent throw.

> throw bonuses will confer a boost to the base catch rate for that Pokemon for that throw and all future throws.

[Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/davidthier/2016/07/22/curveball-nice-excellent-cp-pokemon-go-tricks-to-make-capturing-strong-pokemon-much-easier/#32b589c23c3a) and many other sources declare that this is true as-well.

> The longer you hold onto your Pokéball, the smaller this ring gets before resetting to its largest size. You get an increased capture rate for hitting inside this ring

Comment: Wow - Forbes discusses Pokémon mechanics now? O tempora o mores.

Comment: This is not correct. Neither of your sources are official/substantiated claims. There is no hard evidence/sources to confirm that throw bonus does or does not affect catch rates.

Answer (score 5):

## Updated Answer: The Silph Road's detailed analysis concludes that throw bonus *does* increase your catch rate.* https://thesilphroad.com/science/pokemon-go-throw-bonuses

See @vemonus answer down below: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/288122/75659

### Answer: No one *officially* knows yet. It's frequently a controversial topic in terms of anecdotal evidence: some players say they notice an increase in capture rate, others don't - however, in general, most players seem to be in agreement that it does confer a catch rate bonus.

Below is an explanation of why the capture rate bonuses detailed on certain websites (such as ones in the above answers) are misleading and based on unverified claims.

The closest thing we *had* to an indication that it does affect the rate (besides anecdotal evidence) is within the protobuf file for the game. This is a list of numbers within the game that detail things like medal achievement requirements, experience bonuses, gym experience numbers, etc. I've provided the link below:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf

Within this protobuf we can see that there are only two values related to throw types. The first is an item detail for each type of ball, e.g. for greatball:

```
Items {
  TemplateId: "ITEM_GREAT_BALL"
  Item {
    UniqueId: ITEM_GREAT_BALL
    ItemType: ITEM_TYPE_POKEBALL
    Category: ITEM_CATEGORY_POKEBALL
  }
}
```

and the second lists "thresholds" for each type of throw:

```
Items {
  TemplateId: "ENCOUNTER_SETTINGS"
  EncounterSettings {
    SpinBonusThreshold: 0.5
    ExcellentThrowThreshold: 1.7
    GreatThrowThreshold: 1.3
    NiceThrowThreshold: 1
    MilestoneThreshold: 100
  }
```

Some people saw these numbers and assumed it meant the catch rate multiplier...however others speculate that:

1. this doesn't make sense for spin bonus threshold, since it'd cut the rate in half. it makes more sense if the spin threshold meant (as its name indicates) how much spin is required before its counted as a spin throw
2. the word threshold doesn't make sense given the context (you'd think something more like GreatThrowMultiplier would be more appropriate) and
3. **these numbers more accurately line up with (1 - radius) of the size of the inner circle upon impact.**

To elaborate on point 3:

The [answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272677/what-are-the-possible-catch-bonuses-and-how-much-experience-do-they-reward) says for nice, great, and excellent the percentage of the inner circle to outer circle diameter required would respectively be: 100%, 70%, and 30%.*

*To clarify/reiterate for people unfamiliar with throw types: you have to not only have a smaller circle to get a bonus, you have to hit the pokeball inside the circle as well.*

To translate these numbers into the threshold numbers, all you have to do is see that:

let x = the value upon impact based on the distance

- x = 1 means your pokeball hit the pokemon while the inner circle was the same size as the outer circle
- x = 2 means the inner circle had a radius of 0

Take (2 - x) and you see that the thresholds as detailed in the protobuf line up with the percentages.

For example:

```
2 - ExcellentThrowThreshold
            =
          2 - 1.7
            =
           0.3
            =
           30%
```

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongodev/comments/4vlnwj/pokemon_go_catch_mechanicsformula_discussion/d60jb0j) is a link that details actual data communicated with the servers and basically confirms that the values of 1.00 - 1.99 were the thresholds when that protobuf was published (and also explains how these numbers have to do with why there was no bonus exp for throw types for one patch: the 'x' value was changed from 1.00 - 1.99 to 0.00 - 0.99 and thus no one could achieve the 1.3/1.7 required for the bonus except for hackers).

*NOTE: This is not a definitive source, but it lines up so perfectly with the explanation and numbers that it's very likely true.

Comment: @Vemonus I didn't even look at your answer...someone upvoted this answer recently and I remembered that this information had been updated since I wrote this answer and wanted to reflect the new findings from the silph road. I'm active on the silph road subreddit and had seen this the first day it was posted.

Comment: Yeah, I looked through your edit history and realized you had virtually the same info prior to the edit so I deleted the comment. Someone upvoted my answer as well, right before you updated yours so it looked suspicious, my b

Comment: @Vemonus No worries, I think they upvoted mine too because that's why I came back to edit mine. Upvoted yours and linked it in a few places so people can see it instead of having to visit the website.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://thesilphroad.com/science/pokemon-go-throw-bonuses) was posted today on the Silph Road subreddit and has pretty conclusive evidence that **catch rate is indeed influenced by throw bonuses**.

The controls of the experiment were as follows:

> 1. Only samples collected before the recent TYPE CATCH BONUS mechanic launched were studied
> 2. This dataset only includes balls that were thrown STRAIGHT (See Note 1)
> 3. This study was only conducted on POKE BALLS
> 4. This study excluded Pokemon caught via INCENSE or LURE PATCHES
> 5. Only Pokemon whose BASE CATCH RATE is .4 were included (e.g. Rattata, Pidgey, etc)
> 6. We used % OF MAX CP per species as a basic way to estimate Pokemon level (See Note 2)

Here is a table with the results:

> [image: Catch rate percentages]

From these results, it looks like the 1.1x Nice, 1.3x Great, and 1.5x Excellent multipliers are a bit exaggerated.

From the numbers above, it looks like the actual bonuses are *roughly*:

- Nice: **1.07x**
- Great: **1.20x**
- Excellent: **1.31x**

---

Additionally, another article by the Silph Road was posted yesterday that **confirms** that curveballs *also* increase catch rate. For the full details of this experiment, look [here](https://thesilphroad.com/science/curveball-throw-bonus-in-pokemon-go).

Here is a chart containing the results of the experiment.

[image]