# Is throw bonus for the inner-circle to catch Pokemon continuous or discrete?

Tags: pokemon-go

When catching a Pokemon, there is an inner colored circle that continuously starts at the outer circle and zooms in to zero.  Landing a ball inside the circle gives an XP "throw" bonus depending on how small the circle is when the ball is thrown – Nice!, Great!, or Excellent!  That [throw bonus also corresponds to an increased catch probability](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/282312/176959).

Does the catch probability increase *continuously* as the inner circle size decreases?  Or is the effect of the throw bonus *discrete* and tied to the three named bonus tiers?

Meaning, for example: if I get a Great! throw when the circle has barely shrunk from Nice! size to Great! size, is the catch probability boost the same as if I get Great! right before the circle is about to shrink to Excellent! size?

Comment: I know the comments section is not meant for this, but I just really wanted to mention that I think this is an excellent question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gamepress](https://gamepress.gg/pokemongo/guct-berry-throw-bonus-multipliers) made an analysis about the throw bonus, and these are the results:

Throw Bonuses are not fixed, instead **depends continuously on radius**! The formula we found for catch bonus is:

> Throw = 2−r

where r is the radius of the inner circle, which goes up to 1. That means that when the circle is as big as possible, Throw = 1, and when the circle is as small as possible, Throw = 2.

Since ring size and throw bonus are correlated, we could not be completely sure that the multiplier varies continuously with radius, rather than being a flat bonus for Nice / Great / Excellent.
However, the communication between client and server during a catch **suggests that the bonus is continuous**. What can be seen in the client-server communication is that a variable named `normalized_reticle_size` (NRS) is sent to the server when a ball is thrown.
In other words, for a full-sized circle, `NRS = 1`, and for a circle of minimal radius, `NRS` approaches 2.

Experimental evidence shows that:

| Throw | Nice! | Great! | Excellent! |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Target Ring Size | 70% - 100% | 30% - 70% | ~5% - 30% |
| Bonus (varies with radius) | 1 - 1.3 | 1.3 - 1.7 | 1.7 - ~1.95 |

We also have some lines from the game's code that shows:

```
"excellentThrowThreshold": 1.7,
"greatThrowThreshold": 1.3,
"niceThrowThreshold": 1,
```