# Does spinning the Pokeball/making it sparkle increase the chance of catching Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I can hold my finger on Pokeball and I can spin it before throwing it. Making this with a high speed makes the ball to sparkle. Does this throwing style increase the chance of catching any Pokemon?

P.S. I know the bonuses and I know how to throw a curve ball. You can get all types of bonuses without making it spin or spark. I just want to know if spinning or sparkling increases the chance of catching or not.

Comment: Actually, the opposite. It decreases your chance. See [How do I throw a curve ball?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272611/how-do-i-throw-a-curveball/272612#272612)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I think it is asking if a landed curve ball increases the chances of a catch (ie the Pokemon not escaping)