# What's wrong with my curveball?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've gotten pretty good at landing curveballs. Well, according to **[How to throw a curveball](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272612/125786)**, that's what I *think* I'm doing. But I never seem to get the [10xp bonus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272797/125786) for a curveball, ***whether I hit inside the target or not*** (in my example I happen to get a great throw):

> [image]
>
> [image]

I know for a fact the Curveball Bonus stacks with the others, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd call it a bug. Same goes for curve balls bonuses for normal throws. That should make it even.

Comment: @dly I don't get curve ball bonuses for normal throws. I knew I should have made my GIF a normal throw curveball so people didn't assume this.

Comment: You don't always get that bug bonus, but a few times maybe.

Comment: @dly No I literally haven't seen the word curveball in like a week. Honest to god, all my throws are curveballs, I ***never*** get the bonus. It's so annoying..

Comment: Very strange. I see it bugging only a few times and most of the time it works (Android 5.1).

Comment: @dly Weird huh. iPhone 6+. It makes me want to stop throwing curveballs out of spite but I actually miss more when I do that lol

Comment: I think it's because the game is just a bug-filled mess at the moment. Sometimes I get curveball bonuses when throwing normally, sometimes I don't get "great" or "nice" when hitting inside the colored ring, sometimes my Pokeball does a curveball off the side of the screen when I didn't spin it up... The list goes on.

Comment: fwiw, you *cannot* get Curve AND Nice/Great/Excellent. Only the highest EXP bonus is applied.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this is false

Comment: You have to spin the pokeball first until it have somekind of aura around it.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena Which is the [sparkles which I definitely had.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LsRkk.jpg)

Comment: I have gotten curve ball bonuses from just throwing it straight and hitting the pokemon on the side. I think that the curve balls are just a bit strange and need some work.

Comment: What is the source for "I know for a fact the curveball bonus stacks with the others"? Evidence seems to point to the contrary...

Comment: Curveball and accuracy bonus do stack, but seeing as both rewards are broken you will very rarely get both, let alone one of them reliably.

Comment: It seems like the curveball is currently bugged, I have been only getting it sometimes (Android)

Comment: @Deltharis Seeing it with my actual eyes on my head. They stack, but nothing is working reliably right now.

Comment: @Insane And you've seen many more cases where they didn't stack. I mean, you could be right, but without official source either way stacking (a much rarer occurence) could have been the bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update August 8th 2016**

Curveballs seem to work only by themself. They still don't stack *consistently*.

Curveball + Throw Bonus yields only the Throw Bonus:

[image]

Curveball by itself yields only the Curveball Bonus:

[image]

---

**Update July 31st 2016**

This seems to have been **partially fixed**. I am consistently getting 10XP bonuses for every curveball. However.. it seems now if you throw a curveball *with* a Nice! Great! or Excellent! throw you *only* get the curveball 10XP. Seems Niantic just can't get it right, can they?

---

This seems to be exclusively a game problem.

Once the Pokéball is spinning as I showed in my question, that constitutes the 10XP Curveball bonus. **However**, according to a few people in the comments, the curve ball bonus gets awarded with *normal throws* as well.

Over the past couple days, I kept my eye closely on my bonuses and noticed I *did* get the 10XP Curve ball bonus once or twice, proving that the bonus is **still in the game**, however **broken** — completely.

I have yet to get the Curveball Bonus along with a Nice/Great/Excellent throw bonus, but until proven otherwise this has been shown to be in the game.

Comment: I get more Curveball bonuses throwing straight than throwing curves. It doesn't work at all.

Comment: Only personal experience, but I agree with Chris Hayes. I usually get curve ball bonus only when throwing straight.

Comment: @Zikato So weird. I'll update my answer

Comment: This has supposedly been fixed by the August 8th update

Answer (score 2):

At this point I am certain you cannot get that bonus reliably. I'm not sure if it's a bug the exp bonus got removed.

I've been throwing almost exclusively curveballs for the last 2 days, because I found out about the exp bonus and wanted to get used to landing them. I made a lot of catches with curved throws: most didn't get "great" or "nice" bonuses, few did, I even landed 1 curvebal on a jumping pokemon.

I couldn't get the "curveball" exp bonus even once. My friend had the exact same experience, although, he wasn't focusing on cureballs only.

Comment: Yet dly from the comments is getting them every once in a while on Android. It's good to know that i'm throwing them properly

Comment: I only found out about them recently, but much like "nearby" feature, I've never seen it work.

Comment: I am also still able to get the bonus on Android, although not consistently http://i.imgur.com/06lMJFq

Comment: Yep, I'm using AssistiveTouch / adaptive gestures (so I KNOW I'm throwing the ball the same way) and it's a roll of the dice if I get  a curveball bonus or not.

Answer (score 1):

I got lucky with this shot — wish I had a video, but at least the screenshot shows what I wanted. Curveball bonuses CAN and DO stack, but like all of you, I have had them be anything but consistent. Like the video that was posted showing "when it does work, when it should work, and when it's wrong," I have shared in all of those experiences. I've been experiencing weird things across the board with my throws, so just know the bonuses are generally broken and you're not alone!

Screenshot showing the stacking bonuses:

[image: screenshot showing the stacking bonuses]

Answer (score -2):

You cannot get the curve ball exp bonus plus the nice/great/excellent exp bonus. If you land a nice/great/excellent it will overwrite the curve ball bonus because it grants higher exp. 
The point of the curve ball is for the higher capture rate. Not the exp bonus.

Comment: Not true.. again.. it is possible to stack the bonuses it's just broken

Answer (score -3):

<strike>So I'm 90+% sure you can't stack bonuses -</strike> I've never managed both a curve and a nice/great/excellent throw bonus on the same catch, and I'm throwing almost exclusively curving throws (though they only rarely count as curveballs for the bonus) at this point.  For those saying they can stack, do you have a screenshot with both?

I'm also pretty convinced that the way the throw curves has nothing to do with whether or not you get the curve bonus...  I've thrown straight on throws with my thumb while playing one-handed that have gotten a bonus, while a long sweeping arc that goes off the left side of the screen and sweeps back to hit the pokemon in the center of the screen awarded no bonus.  videos from catches today, some with and others without the bonus.

Any possible explanations I've come up with so far, tend to find contradictions.  Similar throws both do and don't get bonuses at different times.  Even bugs are normally more consistent than this...

Answer (score -5):

You're just not curving it enough. You need to curve it significantly to get the bonus

Comment: I don't think that's true, honestly.

Comment: @Insane if you don't swipe perfectly straight, it will turn into a curve ball.

Comment: @Dragonrage What does that have to do with what I said. If the curve I displayed in my GIF doesn't constitute a curve ball that's madness..